# Is there a reason to link my bank account to Paypal?

Tags: bank-account, paypal

A lot of smaller merchants use using Paypal checkout now.  While I prefer to pay for everything with a credit card to get rewards, Paypal doesn't prefer that and makes me manually update each payment to switch the primary funding source from the default of my bank account.

If I remove the bank account entirely, does that affect how I can use Paypal in general?  Will it default to the credit card as primary funding source then?

Comment: Related (but not duplicates):  http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/181/paypal-wants-me-to-add-a-bank-account-another-funding-source-credit-card-isn and http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1792/what-are-the-risks-of-associating-your-paypal-account-to-your-bank-account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed the bank account because I couldn't change the default, and now it uses my credit card as the default. I haven't noticed any downsides.

I think Paypal is just trying to save paying credit card transaction fees. But I don't much like their user-hostile method of doing so, personally. Most cards kick back some of those fees to cardholders via rewards. If Paypal wants us to use a bank account maybe they should consider giving out an incentive instead of making us do annoying extra clicks on every purchase!